# Flutter-Smartfox server-client

Tags: flutter

I need to connect the smartfoxserver by .dart package.
Do we have library to connect the smartfoxserver, which should support IOS, Android, Windows and web.
But we have some packages for socket.io but not available for smartfoxserver.

Can you provide me the suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't look like they have a flutter sdk. They do have a java client. So I think it is a matter of integrating that into your app. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels might help.

Comment: Thanks for you update and we will look into it